# Is this a right way to descrease size of my docker images?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I am running a deep learning model in Docker container which needs pytorch and Azure ML service.

AML requirement is Ubuntu 18.04 (which by default has only python3.6 and only way to install python3.7+ is from the source from what i was able to find)
transformers in pytorch have a requirement of python 3.7+
and i need pytorch with Cuda so i choose `abinali/pytorch` https://github.com/anibali/docker-pytorch/blob/master/dockerfiles/1.5.0-cuda10.2-ubuntu18.04/Dockerfile

The issue is that the size of the image is around 4GB +. so I wanted to move the PyTorch installation out of the image and run install when the docker is running the container(which increases container running uptime).
Error when running basic torch commands

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 93, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../../../libnvToolsExt.so.1: invalid ELF header
```

so my current docker file is :

```
From nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Create a working directory

# COPY . /app
# WORKDIR /app/
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app


# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user


# Install Miniconda and Python 3.8
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sLo ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh \
 && conda install -y python==3.8.1 \
 && conda clean -ya



CMD ["sh", "-c", "conda install -y -c pytorch cudatoolkit=10.2 \"pytorch=1.5.0=py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0\" \"torchvision=0.6.0=py38_cu102\" && conda clean -ya && python test.py"]
```

Comment: If you are using miniconda, I think you can omit using the `nvidia/cuda` base image, because miniconda will install cuda/cudnn on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Installing runtime dependencies via `CMD` is not a typical way to reduce Docker image size. As the OP noted, this imposes a cost in container startup.

There are a few changes that can be made to the Dockerfile to reduce image size.

1. Use a base image that has miniconda installed but not cuda/cudnn. The OP installs pytorch, cuda, and cudnn via conda, so then there will be duplicate installations of cudnn and cuda in the image (one from the `nvidia/cuda` base image and the other from conda). See the [Azure ML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-custom-docker-image#publicly-available-base-images) for a list of publicly available base images provided by Azure ML.
2. Use `--no-install-recommends` in the `apt-get install` command. This will prevent `apt-get` from installing recommended dependencies, which are not required for the packages' use.
3. Use the `--chown` option in `COPY` to change ownership of the copied files during the `COPY`. Using `RUN chown ...` after a `COPY` will cause the size of `/app` to count twice towards the Docker image's total size.

Here is a Dockerfile that implements my suggestions. This creates a Docker image that is 3.43 GB.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
        sudo \
        git \
        bzip2 \
        libx11-6 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a non-root user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
    && echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# Install pytorch.
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA="false"
RUN conda install --yes python=3.8 \
    && conda install --yes --channel pytorch \
        cudatoolkit=10.2 \
        pytorch=1.5.0=py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0 \
        torchvision=0.6.0=py38_cu102 \
    && conda clean --all --yes

USER user
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=user:user . .

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But, this base image runs on Debian. AML (azure ML service) python SDK does not work on Debian, it needs ubuntu.

Comment: I have never used AML, but the [installation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py) don't say anything about requiring ubuntu. The SDK can be installed with `pip install azureml-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

Probably python-slim base image is out of question since you need **cuda**, but I think you could try multistage building.

You could install all your dependencies in the base first image and then copy them (probably somewhere in `/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/` and `/usr/local/bin/`) into the second image (your release one).

Here is an [article](https://blog.realkinetic.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-python-applications-37d0272c52f3) about multistage building. Hope it helps you.